# React Native: Align mutline Text

Tags: react-native

All i want is to align a multiline text in React native, but when I use a normal input like

```
<Text> long long long long long 
long long long long long long long long
 long long long long long long long long 
long long long long long long long long long 
long long long long long  </Text>
```

I get something like this:

[image]

The firstLine isnot aligned with the rest, how do I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the white space in between the first  tag and the first word, in this case "long". Below, I've linked to an example on RNPlayground as well as pasted the code I used there:

https://rnplay.org/apps/ibfL8w

```
<Text>long long long long long 
long long long long long long long long
 long long long long long long long long 
long long long long long long long long long 
long long long long long</Text>
```

Comment: thanks that is easy, what us this website you are using? seems kind of cery cool ;).

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped. That website is React Native Playground, it is great for just playing around with React Native without having to build entire projects, or testing out ideas / basic functionality. https://rnplay.org/